# Meteor admin panel package

Tags: meteor, meteorite

does meteor have backend admin panel like "rais_admin" or "active admin" in rails for CRUD operations under models?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the teams at the first Meteor Summer Hackathon wrote the [z-mongo-admin](https://github.com/gterrono/meteor-admin-ui) package that gives you a panel for basic CRUD operations. This should have the functionality that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 6/1/2015** - [YES, since version 1.0.2](http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-102-meteor-shell). Once your app is running using `meteor`, run `meteor shell` in the same directory in a separate tab and you'll have a REPL.

<strike>[Not yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096785/does-meteor-have-a-repl). You can run `meteor mongo` in the app directory to access the database. Currently, you need the app running for this to work.</strike>

[Observatory](https://github.com/jhoxray/observatory) is a burgeoning logging and testing framework. Perhaps some kind of REPL will fit in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[Meteor Admin](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin) is an alternative to Houston based on the [Autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) package.

It offers full CRUD based on your collection schemas.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: it is deprecated now

Answer (score 2):

[Meteor Candy](https://www.meteorcandy.com) is an admin panel made just for Meteor. The idea is, everyone builds their Meteor app differently, but we do have commonalities such as the use of Accounts packages, etc, and that's a good place to start.

The package uses Dynamic Import available in Meteor 1.5, which means it adds virtually no weight to your client bundle.

Disclosure: I am the creator of the package

Answer (score 1):

You should try Houston: https://github.com/gterrono/houston

Watch the video presentation here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ASwWEZsAog

Comment: Yep, Houston is exactly what the OP is looking for.